# How do you retrieve device information from a Mobile Website?

Tags: asp.net, mobile, smartphone

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC2 Web Portal with JQuery.Mobile for portable devices (tablets, smart phones etc). While I'am capable of knowing whether the device is portable or not I was wondering if there was an easy way to extract certain information about the device such as brand, model number, OS etc. I am not interested in the IMEI as getting the unique ID of the device is beyond my scope, I jsut need as much general info about the device as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the UserAgent to get probably as much information as you are likely to.

See here : [HttpRequest.Useragent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.useragent.aspx)

Example User Agent for iPhone: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 2_1_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/525.18.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.1.1 Mobile/5A345 Safari/525.20